# Access Share Service Provider (SSP) settings

Tags: sharepoint, mysite, ssp, sharedservicesprovider

How can I access the settings of a Share Service Provider programmatically. Especially how could I retrieve the MySite storage location defined in a SSP's MySite settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.aspx) namespace and [this code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.aspx). You need the [UserProfileManager.MySiteHostUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.mysitehosturl.aspx) property.

You can access the current SSP using reflection. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809/retrieving-the-associated-shared-service-providers-name) for more information.

Comment: Thx! MySiteHostUrl was not exactly what I was looking for but you pushed my in the right direction. I was looking for the UserProfileManager.PersonalSiteInclusion property.

Comment: Ah nice one. There are more My Site properties you can get in some articles here: http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/09/my-site-settings.html